# How to setup trayer to be on all workspaces in xmonad?

Tags: haskell, tray, xmonad

I'm trying to add trayer to my xmonad & xmobar desktop setup.

Here is what I add in `.xinitrc` before `exec xmonad`

```
trayer --edge top --align right --SetDockType true --SetPartialStrut true --expand true --width 18 --height 22 --transparent true --tint 0x000000 &
```

With it I can see it only on first workspace and it's selected by default.

I used to try to ignore it with

```
          ,[ className =? "Trayer" --> doIgnore]
          ,[ resource  =? "trayer" --> doIgnore]
```

but it makes no sense, trayer still being selected (I see selection border) on first workspace...

Here is my current `xmonad.hs` : https://github.com/Heather/xmonad/blob/master/xmonad.hs

xmonad version is 0.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the className for trayer is with a lowercase: "trayer". This should solve the selection issue.

Comment: yes, it works now... I used to test it too but seems like I failed with it previously. Thanks.

Comment: Use `xprop` to discover the className of an application.

Answer (score 1):

The easy-cheesy way to do this is to use [manageDocks](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad-contrib/latest/doc/html/XMonad-Hooks-ManageDocks.html#v%3amanageDocks). It will work for trayer, xmobar, and many other things, too.